# Parsing a Java Properties file in Objective-C for iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I'm looking for a way in the iPhone SDK to read in a Properties file (not the XML flavor) for example this one:

```
# a comment
! a comment

a = a string
b = a string with escape sequences \t \n \r \\ \" \' \ (space) \u0123
c = a string with a continuation line \
    continuation line
d.e.f = another string
```

would result in four key/value pairs.

I can't change this format as it is sent to me by a web service. Can you please direct me?

Thanks,
Emmanuel

Comment: There are numerous C libraries for this linked in [this stack overflow post][1]
[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/874052/830760

Comment: STLSoft is a C++ library which I can't compile in Objective-C/iPhone. The other ones don't work with properties, only config files.

Comment: What makes you to invent another bycicle? Why don't you use XML-like configs?

Comment: @AndreyAtapin: I'm not the one who came up with this scheme. I already said this comes from a web service and I can't change it.

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, Have you parsed the .properties(java) in iOS..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a look at ParseKit http://parsekit.com/. Otherwise you could use RegexKitLite and create some regular expressions.

Comment: Second ParseKit... the "ParseKit Tests" directory contains parsers for plist, arithmetic expressions, json, xml, xpath, and many others as tests.  Java properties files are pretty much a subset of plists, so you should be 95% of the way there with the included code.

Comment: What regular expression do you suggest I use? The problem is for continuation lines \

Comment: I guess a good regular expression would be this one: ^([^#!=].*?)=([^\\\n]|\\.)* (using multiline parsing) but then you may have to trim the results as there could be newlines and and spaces.

Answer (score 3):

I've ended with this solution if anybody is interested :

```
@interface NSDictionary (PropertiesFile)

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithPropertiesFile:(NSString *)file;

@end

@implementation NSDictionary (PropertiesFile)

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithPropertiesFile:(NSString *)file {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *propertyFileContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if (error) return nil;

    NSArray *properties = [propertyFileContent componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    if (properties.count == 0) return nil;

    NSMutableDictionary *result = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:properties.count];
    for (NSString *propertySting in properties) {
        NSArray *property = [propertySting componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];

        if (property.count != 2) continue;

        [result setObject:property[1] forKey:property[0]];
    }
    return result.allKeys.count > 0 ? result : nil;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a perfectly simple parsing problem.  Read a line.  Ignore if comment.  Check for continuation, and read/append continuation lines as needed.  Look for the "=".  Make the left side of the "=" (after trimming white space) the key.  Either parse the right side yourself or put it into an NSString and use stringWithFormat on it to "reduce" any escapes to pure character form.  Return key and reduced right side.

(But refreshing my memory on the [properties file format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) reminds me that:

> The key contains all of the characters in the line starting with the
>   first non-white space character and up to, but not including, the
>   first unescaped '=', ':', or white space character other than a line
>   terminator. All of these key termination characters may be included in
>   the key by escaping them with a preceding backslash character;

So a little scanning of the line is required to separate the key from the rest.  Nothing particularly difficult, though.)

Comment: Since you enumerated 9 steps I wouldn't call it "simple". There's a reason why the original Properties.java is over 1100 lines long.

Comment: Ah, but of that, load0 is only 50 lines long, with one notable subroutine that is another 53 lines long.  I'd call 103 lines fairly simple.  And that's not taking advantage of something like stringWithFormat to crunch the escapes.  The Properties class is so long because of all the other crap they've piled on it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using lex/yacc or flex/bison to generate your own compiler code from a description of the grammar for properties files? I'm not sure if there are any existing grammars defined for a Java properties file, but it seems like it would be a pretty simple grammar to write.

Here's [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427544/what-are-the-standard-grammar-parsers-for-ios) that mentions this approach for general purpose parsing

Answer (score 0):

You can now use `NSRegularExpression` class to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [PropertyParser](https://github.com/mfriesen/BNFParser)

```
NSString *text = @"sample key = sample value";

PropertyParser *propertyParser = [[PropertyParser alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *keyValueMap = [propertyParser parse:text];
```