# How to read a "key"="value" file in objective-C?

Tags: ios

I googled how to read a key=value file in my iOS app but could not find out how. Is there any elegant way to get the values of the file and store them directly in an object?

This file has around 200 lines and it is something like:

```
key1.key2.key3=value
key1.key2.key4=value
key1.key5=value
...
```

EDIT: the format of the provided file is ".properties". Do you know if it is a standard format? oh god, I'm completely lost!!

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of this file and what you would like to do with it? I'm not sure what the format of this data is supposed to look like? Thanks :D

Comment: That's a strange format (by strange, I mean I never saw on like this). Maybe assimiling this kind of format and "translate it" into JSON (maybe find an algorithm/lib on the web).

Comment: @Larme, do you mean that I should translate it to an xml file and then parse it?

Comment: @Borrombombolla: Well, there is a lot of lib that deserialize JSON or XML, so it may use a lot of ressources, but if you can deserialize it into a "known" format, that could be a solution. Not the optimistic one (since you're doing two translation instead of one), but a solution.

Comment: Could it be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324378/parsing-a-java-properties-file-in-objective-c-for-iphone ? Java .properties files?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do the following:

Create your main dict D

Read the file

For each line...

Split the line on the '=' character, you will get K = keys, V = value,

Split K on the '.' character, you will get K[] with the nested keys

Crete temp reference T

now..

```
for (i = 0; i < K[].size; i++) {
    if (i= 0) {
        T = D
    } else {
        T = [T objectForKey: K[i-1]]
    }

    key = K[i]

    if (i = K[].size - 1) {
       [T setObject: V forKey: key]
    } 
    else {
       if( [T objectForKey: key] == nil ) {
           [T setObject: new Dict forKey: key]
       }
    }


}
```

That will execute for each line, at the end you will have your Dict D with nested keys and values.